# TextView can be edited?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I have simple question. I am a new newbie to android. I did got through few tutorials but some responses did not work in my eclipse. I am using version 2.2.

Can we give text view the functionality of edit text of editing?

Comment: for that you can use edittext and you can change the background.

Answer (score 2):

EditText extends TextView and gives it editable functionality,  if you want the EditText to look like TextView, You can change the background and other style properties

Comment: +1. If you can provide a couple of links (if available), I think it'll be nice.

Comment: No... not like this... I want to show the keyboard and let the user input it dynamically

Comment: keyboard does show up when edittext is focused, i dont get what you are trying to do

Comment: @nandeesh: But if it is a textview, keypad does not pop up

Comment: use an edittext but with background different, it will look like a textview

Answer (score 2):

User won't be able to type or edit anything in a text view. It is purely for viewing. But you could set values in a text view with user inputs from an edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TextView can be edited. Try this:

```
TextView.setText();
```

Comment: No... not like this... I want to show the keyboard and let the user input it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

**TextView**

> Displays text to the user and optionally allows them to edit it. A
>   TextView is a complete text editor, however the basic class is
>   configured to not allow editing; see EditText for a subclass that
>   configures the text view for editing.

You can use [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make Textview editable, with android:editable="true",
Please check this link for further reference..
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:editable

Hope this will help you

Comment: can i know what you want to do with textview? so we can decide which view is most suitable for our particular operation.